# How do I select one element out of a class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple rows and in each row is a span which is set to transparent:

```
span {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Now upon the hover of a row, I set the span to be visible by adding the following jQuery:

```
  $('.single-row').hover(function(){
            $('span').css("color", "#999");
        }, function() {
            $('span').css("color", "transparent");
      }
   );
```

However, this effects every row at once rather than the specific row being hovered over.. what syntax do use to effect the specific row being hovered over rather than each row without using id's?

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$('span')`.

Comment: Would this not be easier with pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using  `$(this).find('span')` to select a span inside `current hovered` row

```
 $('.single-row').hover(function(){
           $(this).find('span').css("color", "#999");
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('span').css("color", "transparent");  
      } 
   );
```

**Or use a shortcut**  `$('span',this)`

```
$('.single-row').hover(function(){
        $('span',this).css("color", "#999");
    }, function() {
       $('span',this).css("color", "transparent");  
  }
```

);

Comment: `$("span", this).css`

Comment: Which is a shortcut for `$(this).find('span')`

Comment: A really unnecessary shortcut IMHO (it's so much less readable than `.find`, and saves like five keystrokes)

Comment: @DanielBeck Agree. Edited for  that purpose

Answer (score 1):

The javascript method in the currently-accepted answer will work fine (provided the bug mentioned in comments is fixed) -- but just for completeness, a pure CSS version of this would be

```
.single-row span {color: transparent}
.single-row:hover span {color: #999}
```